# PHP Functions will not create the table correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write some reusable code to create MySQL databases as an exercise. The code I've written connects to MySQL (connectDb function), then creates the database (makeDb function) but it will not create the table on the first pass. It works on the second pass (ie, refresh the page) so I know my createTable function works. I just can't figure out why it doesn't work on the first pass. Could someone please take a look and tell me what I'm missing?

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass); //variable for original connection
$db_con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname); //database connection


/*==== MYSQL Connection and Database Creation ====== */
function connectDb($con){
    //Create connection or die trying
    if (!$con){
        echo "<script>alert('Failed to connect to MySQL')</script>";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Connected to MySQL successfully.\n</p>";
    }
    return;
}

function makeDb($con, $dbname){
    //creates the main database if it is not already created

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);
    $db_create = "CREATE DATABASE ".$dbname; //create database

    if(!$db_select) {

        /*database could not be selected or is not created so we'll go ahead
         * and create one and throw an error if we can't*/

        if (!mysqli_query($con, $db_create)){
            echo "<script>alert('Error creating database')</script>";
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            echo "</p>Database created successfully. \n </p>";
        }

      }
    else{
        echo "<p>Database selected!</p>";
    }
    return;
}

/*===== CREATE THE TABLES ============*/

function createTableSQL($tabName, $columns){

    /*CREATES THE SQL Statement for Table Creation*/

    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' .$tabName.' (';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++){
        $sql = $sql .= $columns[$i];

        if($i < count($columns)-1){
            $sql = $sql .= ", ";
        }

        else {
            $sql = $sql .=")";
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}
function createTable($db_con, $tabName, $sql){

    /*Creates the a table. The table name and sql statement variables are set 
    outside the function.*/
    $select_sql = "SELECT 1 from ".$tabName." Limit 1";

    if (!mysqli_query($db_con, $select_sql)){
        //table does not exit. Attempt to create table
        if (!mysqli_query($db_con, $sql)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Error creating the ".$tabName." table.')</script>";
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>".$tabName." table created successfully!\n</p>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>".$tabName." table exists!\n</p>";
    }
    return;

}

function playerTable($db_con){


    //Check if the Players Table exists and create it if it does not.

    $tabName = "Players";

    $columns = array(
    "id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY",
    "playername VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL",
    "charname VARCHAR (30)",
    "class VARCHAR (30)",
    "race VARCHAR (30)",
    "level INT(2)");

     $sql = createTableSQL($tabName, $columns);
     createTable($db_con, $tabName, $sql);

     return;
}

connectDb($con); //Make the database connection
makeDb($con, $dbname); //Create the database
playerTable($db_con); // Create the table
```

Comment: I dont think it is logical to attempt to select a database that you have not yet created !!!!!

Comment: `connectDb($con)` does not actually do anything

Comment: It tests the database connection and exits if it can't connect. Should I move that operation to somewhere else in the code? I'm honestly asking because I'm learning. My understanding is that it would make sense to test the connection before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing this line before your database exists:

```
$db_con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname);
```

Since `$dbname` hasn't been created yet, this operation will fail and `$db_con` won't be a valid connection to anything.  So this will fail:

```
playerTable($db_con);
```

On the "second pass" it succeeds because the database exists.

Just hold off on connecting to the database until it's been created:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass);
connectDb($con);
makeDb($con, $dbname);

$db_con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname);
playerTable($db_con);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I didn't figure that out. Thanks so much.